# Copy and launch EC2 and RDS in another account

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to copy and launch an EC2 instance in another account but the instance is using an RDS instance.

I know I can make an image snapshot of the EC2 and the RDS and then launch them on the other account, my question is if I launch on another account the copy of both of both would they start to work normally as long as they stay on the same security group or would not be able to comunicate and I would have to change some configuration on the EC2 instance so it can find the databse?

The EC2 instance is a regular wordpress running on linux, the database is a mySQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change the configuration of the EC2 instance so it has the database name. This is probably within whatever application runs on the instance, but if the application is written well it could be passed to the application when the VM starts somehow.

You would also have to make sure subnets are set up in a way that works, security groups / NACLs are set, and there may be a few other small things as well - none come to mind right now.